# how to apply patch generated with diff linux command on svn repo

Tags: linux, svn, patch

I have a patch generated with diff command:

```
diff -ruN orig/ new/ > file.patch
```

I want to apply this patch on svn repo with svn utilities.
How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ svn help patch
```

> `patch`: Apply a patch to a working copy.
>
> usage: `patch PATCHFILE [WCPATH]`
>
> Apply a unidiff patch in `PATCHFILE` to the working copy `WCPATH`.
>   If `WCPATH` is omitted, '.' is assumed.
>
> A unidiff patch suitable for application to a working copy can be
>   produced with the `svn diff` command or third-party diffing tools.
>   Any non-unidiff content of `PATCHFILE` is ignored, except for Subversion
>   property diffs as produced by `svn diff`.